# What is better in DB design? Have an explicit value or deduce that value from others in the model?

Tags: database, database-design, schema

For example, I have a model that has a 'inDate' and 'outDate'. The model is 'active'while the thing we are tracking is 'in' and goes inactive when it goes 'out'.

Is it better to have an 'active' property or to just deduce the active state by checking if the outDate exists or not?

I find the active state to be a little redundant because it can't be active if it has an 'outDate' and it can't be inactive if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are going to use the table and how much data is going to be there in worst case. So you need to find out the answers for these.

I would do it this way. A lookup table that will hold all valid states and a activity table to record timestamps for each state change.

```
State_ID   Description
0          IN
1          OUT
...
...
...


State Activity

State     State_Date
0              t1
1              t2
...
...
...
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect. I was already applying something similar to this to get a history of events for other models, but it perfectly applies here too! Thanks!